Story about a plantation owner
I read a short story about a man who buys a plantation producing a valuable crop which is very tough. Then the plantation comes under attack by a pest (creature) that no one has been able to stop.
He works out that the creature eats the crop, so must be made of the same stuff as the crop. Sets a trap accordingly and finds the captured creatures make him good money.
I don't know the name of the story or the name of the writer.

Hi, welcome to SF&F.  When and where did you read this?  What about the creatures is worth money?

Is the story set on Earth or on another planet?

Why haven't other people been able to stop the critters?  Are they smart, or really tough, or very fast...

Similarities to this question, which was answered with "The Howling Bounders" by Jack Vance. I've never read the story. https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/265765/story-man-purchases-plantation-on-planet-finds-unstoppable-infestation-uses

Thats the one. Howling Bounders by Jack Vance.
I read it perhaps 40 years ago. What makes the creatures worth the money is that they are basically the same stuff as the crop they eat, resilian. The sci-fi version of what we now call carbon-fibre

Accepted via comment so closing as duplicate.
